# Returning the number of child items in MSXML

Tags: c++, xml, msxml

I am using MSXML to parse an xml file.
I have had some success but have encountered a problem.

This is a much simplified example of the file I am trying to parse...

```
<root>
    <main_menu Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb" Attr_3 = "cccc" />
        <sub_menu Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb" Attr_3 = "cccc" > 
            <box Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb" Attr_3 = "cccc"  />
            <box Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb" Attr_3 = "cccc"  />
        </sub_menu> 

        <box Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb" Attr_3 = "cccc"  />

        <sub_menu Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb" Attr_3 = "cccc"  >    
            <list Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb" Attr_3 = "cccc" >
                <item Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb"  Attr_3 = "cccc"  />                  
                <item Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb"  Attr_3 = "cccc"  />                              
            </list>
        </sub_menu> 

        <box Attr_1 = "aaaa" Attr_2 = "bbbb" Attr_3 = "cccc"  />
    </main_item>
```

What I need to do is find out the number of child items associated with the node "sub_menu" so that I can iterate through them all. To do this I have used something similar to this...

```
MSXML::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr  pMainItem;
MSXML::IXMLDOMNodePtr pNode;   

pMainItem = pRootNode->selectNodes("/root/main_item/sub_menu*");

printf("%u main items\n", pMainItem->Getlength());

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)      // 3 = Magic Number                        
{
   pNode = pMainItem->item[i];
   length = pNode->attributes->Getlength();           
   etc
```

The problem is - because I have 2 nodes called "sub_menu" at the same level in the structure, pMainItem->Getlength() returns 3 instead of 2. It counts the total number of child items for all nodes called sub_menu. What I need is the number of child items for the FIRST instance of sub_menu. Consequently I have no way to limit the number of iterations of my for loop (hence the magic number)

I dont have the option to change the structure of the XML file to make the node names more unique. II get the feeling that there must be a different method to achieve what I want but my knowledge of XML and C++ is currently fairly limited.

Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: `/root/main_item/sub_menu*` is not syntactically correct XPath, is that `/root/main_item/sub_menu/*`? In that case changing it to `/root/main_item/sub_menu[1]/*` should give the child elements of the first `sub_menu`.

Comment: Yes - sorry that is the correct path! This has worked perfectly - THANKS